# How to bind server side events on client objects and vice versa with meteor

Tags: javascript, events, rpc, meteor

Is it possible to directly bind server side events to client side objects in meteor?

I would like to update a view for example when a server side event triggers. On the other hand I'd like to fire a server side method when a user clicks a view item.

I could use [Meteor#methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) for all the events but that seems odd.

Or can I specify an eventhandler for example using [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter) outside the client- and server-scope so that it is available on both sides and trigger/bind events ob that very object?

Some confused about that I am thankful for hints into the right direction.

Regards
Felix

**Update:**

Using Meteor#methods works great in case user events should be mapped to server side actions. The other way around is still unclear. Asynchronous actions on serverside could persist their results in a collection which is pub/sub'ed to the client, which in turn could update some view due to the reactive context. But thats odd, cause persisting that kind of info is slow, wasted space and time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about storing the progress in Session?  You could do something like this:

```
Template.progress.value = function() {
    return Session.get('progress');
}
```

Then, whenever you update the Session on the server, the client template will automatically get those changes.

Out of curiosity, how exactly are you performing asynchronous actions on the server?  I'm still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the Collection.observe on the server side to 'observe' events on the Collection as clients are inserting, updating, removing, etc...  That might be a start if you are focused on Collections alone.  I used it like a sort of server side event loop to watch for collection changes.

When a user clicks on something in a view try binding a Template Event to the View css selector and then calling a Meteor method which will notify the server of the event.  See the examples of binding a key handler and/or button handlers to a Template.entry.event which then call a Meteor method notifying the server that something happened.

Comment: Steeve, thx for your answer. Meteor#methods work great for client->server. But what about the other way around. I for example traverse a RESTful API endpoint on serverside and would like to show some progress (# of synced resources) on the client. Any suggestions from your side?

Comment: @GeorgieF I am not sure I fully understand you.  I am assuming you want a client to be able to see how many of the endpoints are in use or synced with other clients?  If so, implement it like logging and have the client that wants to watch subscribe to the log event table and filter by resource endpoint and action.

Comment: the current setup does exactly that. The server portion of my code traverses a RESTful API and transfers a lot of data into the Meteor server where it's persisted. I'd like to show some progress information on the client during this process is running. Therefore I created a server side collection, published it and subscribed to it on the client side. That works, but results in many many write operations on server side everytime a API-tree's leaf is persisted. Would'nt it be nice to have some memory only object that can be published to the client? Is'nt there something?

Comment: @GeorgieF if you are using Meteor collections then you are basically using Mongo collections, thus the writes.  I believe you would either have to write (or wait for someone else to write) a package for Meteor to do this.  Maybe a memchached package would do for you then.  I think that is about as useful as I can be at this moment though.  I hope I helped this some.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. Maybe developing a package likr that could be beneficial.

Comment: @GeorgieF see the docs, does this help? "If you pass null as the name, then you're creating a local collection. It's not synchronized anywhere; it's just a local scratchpad that supports Mongo-style find, insert, update, and remove operations. (On both the client and the server, this scratchpad is implemented using Minimongo.)"

Comment: Worth trying, did not so far. But as far as I understand it creates a Mongo collection no matter where you are - client or server but does not bind the reactive context on that. So I'd loose exactly what I needed. Anyway, I'll give it a try and report back. Thx again.